# What function to use to get and cache the latest blockhash with the @solana/web3.js library?

Tags: web3.js

I found the [following YouTube short](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hvCSuCauCA) on the official Solana channel.

At 0:20 min you can see a part of his code where he uses and caches the result from the BlockHash function.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to find anything about this function. Neither in [the docs](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js) nor when I search [the repository on GitHub](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js).

Does someone know where I can find more information about this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the `getLatestBlockhash` method on the `Connection` class that's exported by `@solana/web3.js`

You can find the reference in the documentation [here](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getLatestBlockhash).

### Basic usage

To use it, you need to initialize the Connection class and you can call it, like so:

```
import { Connection } from '@solana/web3.js'
const conn = new Connection('your-rpc-endpoint', 'confirmed')
const result = await conn.getLatestBlockhash()
console.log(result)
```

This will output the `blockhash` and the `lastValidBlockHeight`:

```
{
  blockhash: 'G4oTG19N9mkWfNv6VUJzTtGCTFx2xw4JgWF1MhKA4hdG',
  lastValidBlockHeight: 225956979
}
```

### Adding a cache

The `@solana/web3.js` package does not come with cache out of the box, but it's pretty easy to add it yourself.

In the example below, I'm using the library [lru-cache](https://npm.im/lru-cache) but you can use other libraries.

To get this working, we first install the package and add it to our imports:

```
import { Connection } from '@solana/web3.js'
import { LRUCache } from 'lru-cache'
```

Next up, we define a cache that lives for 30 seconds:

```
// We need our connection
const conn = new Connection('your-rpc-endpoint', 'confirmed')

const cache = new LRUCache<string, string>({
  max: 1000,
  // 30 seconds
  ttl: 1000 * 30,
  // Define the fetch method for this cache
  fetchMethod: async () => {
    const result = await conn.getLatestBlockhash()
    console.log(`[CACHE WRITE] blockhash ${result.blockhash}`)
    return result.blockhash
  }
})
```

With this in place, we can call the `fetch()` function on the `cache` instance. It will retrieve the blockhash from the cache; if not found there, it will obtain it from Solana and store it in the cache.

You can see an example here:

```
async function main() {
  // Show the cached blockhash for 60 seconds
  const attempts = 60
  for (let i = 0; i < attempts; i++) {
    const start = Date.now()
    // Get the cached blockhash
    const blockhash = await cache.fetch('blockhash')
    // If the blockhash is not cached, throw an error
    if (!blockhash) {
      throw new Error('Expected blockhash')
    }
    // Show the blockhash
    console.log(`[CACHE READ] blockhash ${blockhash} took ${Date.now() - start}ms`)
    // Wait 1 second
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
  }
}

main()
```

The output looks something like this:

```
[CACHE WRITE] blockhash DbFB5dTNgUAfshKQVva7hCiXJbUnUeWq8PHfUoFjJKF9
[CACHE READ] blockhash DbFB5dTNgUAfshKQVva7hCiXJbUnUeWq8PHfUoFjJKF9 took 544ms
[CACHE READ] blockhash DbFB5dTNgUAfshKQVva7hCiXJbUnUeWq8PHfUoFjJKF9 took 0ms
[CACHE READ] blockhash DbFB5dTNgUAfshKQVva7hCiXJbUnUeWq8PHfUoFjJKF9 took 0ms
[CACHE READ] blockhash DbFB5dTNgUAfshKQVva7hCiXJbUnUeWq8PHfUoFjJKF9 took 0ms
[CACHE READ] blockhash DbFB5dTNgUAfshKQVva7hCiXJbUnUeWq8PHfUoFjJKF9 took 3ms
[CACHE READ] blockhash DbFB5dTNgUAfshKQVva7hCiXJbUnUeWq8PHfUoFjJKF9 took 0ms
[CACHE READ] blockhash DbFB5dTNgUAfshKQVva7hCiXJbUnUeWq8PHfUoFjJKF9 took 0ms
[CACHE READ] blockhash DbFB5dTNgUAfshKQVva7hCiXJbUnUeWq8PHfUoFjJKF9 took 1ms
........
```

From looking at the results, there is a huge benefit in doing this and might lead to an enhanced user experience depending on the app.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But how I can set the caching here? In the YouTube short he sets a caching for 15 seconds using a maxSeconds parameter.

Comment: In the YouTube short, they show the Unity SDK which has caching built in. The JavaScript SDK (`@solana/web3.js`) does not have this. 

I'll update my post to add a caching example.

Comment: You should configure `fetchMethod` on the `lru-cache` itself; that way you don't have to build your own `getCachedBlockhash()` cache primer.

Comment: Never heard of that option Steve, going to check it out and update my post accordingly!